# Infinite loop in bubble sort over Traversable in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation, bubble-sort, traversable

I am trying to implement a bubble sort over any traversable container using the [Tardis](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tardis-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Tardis.html) monad.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

module Main where

import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Monad.Tardis
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Traversable
import Data.Tuple
import Debug.Trace

newtype Finished = Finished { isFinished :: Bool }

instance Monoid Finished where
  mempty = Finished False
  mappend (Finished a) (Finished b) = Finished (a || b)

-- | A single iteration of bubble sort over a list.
-- If the list is unmodified, return 'Finished' 'True', else 'False'
bubble :: Ord a => [a] -> (Finished, [a])
bubble (x:y:xs)
  | x <= y = bimap id                       (x:) (bubble (y:xs))
  | x  > y = bimap (const $ Finished False) (y:) (bubble (x:xs))
bubble as = (Finished True, as)

-- | A single iteration of bubble sort over a 'Traversable'.
-- If the list is unmodified, return 'Finished' 'True', else 'Finished' 'False'
bubbleTraversable :: (Traversable t, Ord a, NFData a, Show a) => t a -> (Finished, t a)
bubbleTraversable t = extract $ flip runTardis (initFuture, initPast) $ forM t $ \here -> do
  sendPast (Just here)
  (mp, finished) <- getPast
  -- For the first element use the first element,
  -- else the biggest of the preceding.
  let this = case mp of { Nothing -> here; Just a -> a }
  mf <- force <$> getFuture -- Tardis uses lazy pattern matching,
                            -- so force has no effect here, I guess.
  traceM "1"
  traceShowM mf -- Here the program enters an infinite loop.
  traceM "2"
  case mf of
    Nothing -> do
      -- If this is the last element, there is nothing to do.
      return this
    Just next -> do
      if this <= next
        -- Store the smaller element here
        -- and give the bigger into the future.
        then do
          sendFuture (Just next, finished)
          return this
        else do
          sendFuture (Just this, Finished False)
          return next
  where
    extract :: (Traversable t) => (t a, (Maybe a, (Maybe a, Finished))) -> (Finished, t a)
    extract = swap . (snd . snd <$>)

    initPast = (Nothing, Finished True)
    initFuture = Nothing

-- | Sort a list using bubble sort.
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort = snd . head . dropWhile (not . isFinished . fst) . iterate (bubble =<<) . (Finished False,)

-- | Sort a 'Traversable' using bubble sort.
sortTraversable :: (Traversable t, Ord a, NFData a, Show a) => t a -> t a
sortTraversable = snd . head . dropWhile (not . isFinished . fst) . iterate (bubbleTraversable =<<) . (Finished False,)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ sort ([1,4,2,5,2,5,7,3,2] :: [Int]) -- works like a charm
  print $ sortTraversable ([1,4,2,5,2,5,7,3,2] :: [Int]) -- breaks
```

The main difference between `bubble` and `bubbleTraversable` is the handling of the `Finished` flag: In `bubble` we assume that the right-most element is already sorted and change the flag, if the elements to the left of it aren't; in `bubbleTraversable` we do it the other way around.

While trying to evaluate `mf` in `bubbleTraversable`the program enters an infinite loop in the lazy references as evidenced by the ghc output `<<loop>>`.

The problem is probably, that `forM` tries to evaluate the elements successively, before the monadic chaining takes place (especially since `forM` is `flip traverse` for lists). Is there any way to rescue this implementation?

Comment: This is an excellent question, which I don't have time to look into at the moment. I would like to point out this discussion on sorting Traversables: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/63a4ea/fast_total_sorting_of_arbitrary_traversable/ If you weren't aware of it already, maybe you could take some ideas from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, style-wise, `Finished = Data.Monoid.Any` (but you only use the `Monoid` bit for `(bubble =<<)` when it may as well be `bubble . snd`, so I just dropped it for `Bool`), `head . dropWhile (not . isFinished . fst) = fromJust . find (isFinished . fst)`, `case x of { Nothing -> default; Just t = f t } = maybe default f x`, and `maybe default id = fromMaybe default`.

Second, your assumption that `force` does nothing in `Tardis` is wrong. Thunks don't "remember" they were created in a lazy-pattern match. `force` itself does nothing, but when the thunk it produces is evaluated, it causes the thunk it was given to be evaluated to NF, no exceptions. In your case, that `case mf of ...` evaluates `mf` to normal form (instead of just WHNF) because `mf` has `force` in it. I don't believe it's causing any problems here, though.

The real problem is that you are "deciding what to do" depending on a future value. This means you are matching on a future value, and then you are using that future value to produce a `Tardis` computation that gets `(>>=)`'d into the one that produces that value. This is a no-no. If it's any clearer: `` runTardis (do { x <- getFuture; x `seq` return () }) ((),()) = _|_ `` but `` runTardis (do { x <- getFuture; return $ x `seq` () }) ((),()) = ((),((),())) ``. You are allowed to use a future value to create a pure value, but you cannot use it to decide the `Tardis` you will run. In your code, this is when you try `case mf of { Nothing -> do ...; Just x -> do ... }`.

This also means that `traceShowM` is causing an issue all by itself, as printing something in `IO` evaluates it deeply (`traceShowM` is approximately `unsafePerformIO . (return () <$) . print`). `mf` needs to be evaluated as the `unsafePerformIO` is executing, but `mf` depends on evaluating the `Tardis` operations that come after the `traceShowM`, but `traceShowM` forces the `print` to be done before it allows the next `Tardis` operation (`return ()`) to be revealed. `<<loop>>`!

Here's the fixed version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Tardis
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Tuple
import Data.List hiding (sort)
import Data.Maybe

-- | A single iteration of bubble sort over a list.
-- If the list is unmodified, return 'True', else 'False'
bubble :: Ord a => [a] -> (Bool, [a])
bubble (x:y:xs)
  | x <= y = bimap id            (x:) (bubble (y:xs))
  | x  > y = bimap (const False) (y:) (bubble (x:xs))
bubble as = (True, as)

-- | A single iteration of bubble sort over a 'Traversable'.
-- If the list is unmodified, return 'True', else 'False'
bubbleTraversable :: (Traversable t, Ord a) => t a -> (Bool, t a)
bubbleTraversable t = extract $ flip runTardis init $ forM t $ \here -> do
  -- Give the current element to the past so it will have sent us biggest element
  -- so far seen. 
  sendPast (Just here)
  (mp, finished) <- getPast
  let this = fromMaybe here mp


  -- Given this element in the present and that element from the future,
  -- swap them if needed.
  -- force is fine here
  mf <- getFuture
  let (this', that', finished') = fromMaybe (this, mf, finished) $ do
                                    that <- mf
                                    guard $ that < this
                                    return (that, Just this, False)

  -- Send the bigger element back to the future
  -- Can't use mf to decide whether or not you sendFuture, but you can use it
  -- to decide WHAT you sendFuture.
  sendFuture (that', finished')

  -- Replace the element at this location with the one that belongs here
  return this'
  where
    -- No need to be clever
    extract (a, (_, (_, b))) = (b, a)
    init = (Nothing, (Nothing, True))

-- | Sort a list using bubble sort.
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort = snd . fromJust . find fst . iterate (bubble . snd) . (False,)

-- | Sort a 'Traversable' using bubble sort.
sortTraversable :: (Traversable t, Ord a) => t a -> t a
sortTraversable = snd . fromJust . find fst . iterate (bubbleTraversable . snd) . (False,)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ sort ([1,4,2,5,2,5,7,3,2] :: [Int]) -- works like a charm
  print $ sortTraversable ([1,4,2,5,2,5,7,3,2] :: [Int]) -- works like a polymorphic charm

-- Demonstration that force does work in Tardis
checkForce = fst $ sortTraversable [(1, ""), (2, undefined)] !! 1
-- checkForce = 2 if there is no force
-- checkForce = _|_ if there is a force
```

If you still want to `trace` `mf`, you can `mf <- traceShowId <$> getFuture`, but you may not get any well-defined order to the messages (don't expect time to make sense inside a `Tardis`!), though in this case it seems to just print the tails of the lists backwards.